# Find Max in String value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, casting, max

I have a mysql table with fields like id,Name,File path,created_by,created_on.

In the table I have to find the max(file_path) group by id.

For example,I am having file_path as

```
TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246_6.pdf,
TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246_7.pdf,
TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246_8.pdf,
TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246_9.pdf,
TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246_10.pdf
```

for id as 1.

If I run the query

```
select max(file_path) from table where id='1'
```

It shows the value as `TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246_9.pdf` instead of `TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246_10.pdf` because it compares this as string.

I have tried

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_path, '_', -3)  AS SIGNED) as num FROM `table`
```

But it shows 0 as result.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: So store the filename as 06,07,08,09,10, etc

Comment: I need to store the file name which was stored in the folder.

Comment: I seriously think you should revise your file naming policy. You're making this harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first part of the file path is the same for a given id, you want to get things in the right order.

```
select file_path
from table
where id = '1'
order by (substring_index(file_path, '_', -1) + 0) desc
limit 1;
```

Note that your `substring_index()` expression uses -3, whereas this uses -1.  In the first example, the `substring_index()` will return '1.pdf'.  The + 0 does silent conversion, so it will convert leading digits and not return an error -- giving "1" in this case.

Comment: The above solution works fine but I have to use this with another query using Inner Join.How can I do that. "select o.order_id,o.order_details,max(f.file_path) from order o inner join filetable f on f.id=o.order_id".I need to use these type of cases.

Comment: @rekhas . . . That sounds like a different question to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can select only the progressive number using [substring()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php)

```
SUBSTRING('TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246_10.pdf', 25, 2) --10
```

You should rename your files adding a zero, like 07, 08, etc.

The query would be

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(file_path, 26, 2))
FROM table
WHERE id = '1'
```

EDIT:
Given that the filename may change, and the only sure thing is that it ends with *.pdf*, you must use negative numbers like this:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(file_path, -5, 2))
FROM table
WHERE id = '1'
```

Comment: The name (TTE_RODRIGUEZ_100001_246) is not static.It may be TTE_ELIZABETH_101_22 something like this.So your solution could not match my requirement.

Comment: You're right, I should have done it with negative numbers (starting from the end of the filename). I'll edit my answer

Comment: Cannot test right now (I'm working on SQL Server) but I followed the linked page, only the legth has to be positive. I'll edit my answer again, sorry :D